# SwiftUI: Adding padding of just 1 between Text creates a huge padding - how to actually make a small padding?

Tags: swiftui

I have `Texts` inside `VStack`, between which I would like to add a bit of whitespace.

However, setting a minimal possible padding (= 1) creates a padding that is too huge, while padding of zero creates no padding at all.

It seems that SwiftUI somehow computes `realPadding = declaredPadding > 0 ? declaredPadding + 8 : 0`, which makes smaller padding unachievable.

Why is this happening? Is this behaviour actually documented somewhere?

Right now it seems that if I want to have eg. 2pt gap between texts, I'm out of luck.

Is there a way to actually get a padding between Text views smaller than what I get with `.padding(.bottom, 1)`?

Nikita Tonsky [criticizes](https://tonsky.me/blog/swiftui/) this "automagic" behavior, but he didn't come up with solution.

Sample code to be pasted into a playground:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                VStack{
                    Text("Hello World")
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .padding(.bottom, 0)
                    Text("padding 0")
                        .background(Color.red)
                }
                .padding()
                
                VStack{
                    Text("Hello World")
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .padding(.bottom, 1)
                    Text("padding 1 - a huge step-up from 0, why?")
                        .background(Color.red)
                }
                .padding()
                
                VStack{
                    Text("Hello World")
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .padding(.bottom, 2)
                    Text("padding 2 - just 1 pt larger than 1")
                        .background(Color.red)
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

How it looks:

[image: SwiftUI padding bug?]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add `(spacing: 0)` to VStack, padding is added by exactly 1.

```
VStack(spacing: 0) { // here
    Text("Hello World")
        .background(Color.red)
        .padding(.bottom, 1)
    Text("padding 1 - a huge step-up from 0, why?")
        .background(Color.red)
}
.padding()
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you Taeeun! This is it - setting explicit padding turns off the magic :).

Comment: the default value of "spacing" is hard to understand, especially for who have worked with CSS layouts.